# How to use setTimeout and get a return variable?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a function geocode that works... I'm trying to implement a delay to prevent over query limit errors, and here is my javascript:

```
tmpResult = null; 
setTimeout(function() { 
    tmpResult = geocode(facilities[j],cities[j],states[j]);
}, 100);
```

The variable `tmpResult` has the results of my geocode.. however, `tmpResult` is `null` when I run the script.. is there something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tmpResult` is perfectly valid when the `setTimeout()` runs and afterwards.  The issue for you is probably that you are trying to use `tmpResult` BEFORE the `setTimeout()` has run.  Remember, it will run 100ms into the future.  Your other javascript will continue to run before that.

What you need to do is use the value of `tmpResult` from within the `setTimeout()` or call some function and pass it the value of `tmpResult`.

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    var tmpResult = geocode(facilities[j],cities[j],states[j]);
    callMyFunction(tmpResult);
}, 100);
```

`setTimeout()` is asynchronous and you cannot program synchronously when using it.  You must code asynchronously which means the value of `tmpResult` is not valid until the timer callback executes so you can't try to use it before the timer callback fires.

As you have discovered, if you try to do this:

```
var tmpResult = null;
setTimeout(function() { 
    tmpResult = geocode(facilities[j],cities[j],states[j]);
}, 100);
console.log(tmpResult);
```

It will not work because your `console.log(tmpResult)` statement will run BEFORE the timer fires, thus `tmpResult` does not yet have a value.

---

FYI, you should make sure that `geocode()` is not also an asynchronous function because if it is, then you will have to code asynchronously with it also.

Comment: After digging through many many pages looking for a thorough explanation of setTimeout(), this is the best I've come across. Thanks so much for the detailed response!